# Data Structure to keep continuous stream of elements based on count

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Input: Continuous stream of Set of elements with their count, I mean set as ADT and not as a python set, plus a minCount variable

For e.g`{'a': 3, 'b':1, 'c':2}, minCount = 3`

I will get n such set of elements with their counts. The minCount is static for for all sets.

What I want to do is have a data structure in which I can move elements as their count increases.

Suppose minCount is 3. Then when I get the example first set, a will be present in one list `A` as it satisfies minCount condition, while b and c do not and are present in list `B`. Now if the next set of count is

```
{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c': 2, 'd':1}
```

then a is not impacted as it's overall count is 4 but b and c both have gone above 3, so the first list `A` will have a,b,c with their overall count. d will be in list `B`. Obviously I can easily do this with two lists. Another way is to get all elements with their count and then do a pass over this to get elements which satisfy minCount.

Is there a better way to do this than what I described? I do not need approximate answers.

Comment: A data structure question to be closed?

Answer (score 0):

2 hash tables seems like the best way to go - one for elements below and one for elements above (and equal to) `minCount`.

Given that hash tables have O(1) expected insert / lookup / update / delete cost, you can't, asymptotically, do much better than that.

Comment: I have implemented it exactly like that.